# Ionic/Angular 2 - App crashes trying to show undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

Not sure if this is an ionic or angular issue specifically. I don't know what the {{ }} is called so it's making it difficult to find any solution on this.

I have a fairly simple bit of HTML to display

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <h2>Record: {{teamStanding.wins}}-{{teamStanding.losses}}</h2>
          <p>Coach: {{team.coach}}</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <!-- Placeholder -->
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
 </ion-content>
```

teamStanding and team is populated with data in ionViewDidLoad

Problem is, when navigating to this page I get errors about "Cannot Read Property 'wins' of undefined"
It's doing this without ever doing ionViewDidLoad - it just never hits it, it throws the error and stops everything.

Now if this was angularJS {{teamStanding.wins}} would just be blank until it stopped being undefined... what's even more confusing is this project I'm working on is a follow along with a tutorial off pluralsight where this exact same code executes WITHOUT errors - seemingly putting undefined data into the {{ }}'s for the instructor doesn't cause errors for him. What gives? Why doesn't this fail silently like I would expect?

Obviously if I declare teamStanding as an empty object, this code executes without error, but if I was doing something like teamStanding.thing.thing.thing.thing I would need to create a temp/dummy object {thing: {thing: {thing: {thing: } } } } just to get this to work until ionViewDidLoad!

Comment: use the safe navigation operator `?` `{{teamStanding?.wins}}` this will tell angular to check if `teamStanding` exists before trying to access `teamStanding.wins`. An alternative is to wrap `ion-col` in an ngIf so the inner elements are not rendered until `teamStanding` exists `<ion-col *ngIf="teamStandings">...</ion-col>`

Comment: Pluralsight much?  Had this same issue and fixed it with the SNO.  Thanks for the post and solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's specifically what the Safe Navigation Operator is for. If you are familiar with the Elvis operator in other languages, it's the same thing. So, in your example, it would be:

```
{{ teamStanding?.wins }} - {{ teamStanding?.losses }}
```

This way, a null or undefined object won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what the {{ }} is called so it's making it difficult to find any solution on this.
>   That calls "Interpolation", "Data Bindings".

For solve your problem I suggest you use [safe operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) because probably the teamStanding property really is undefined when HTML template try get it.